# Contraction Banach theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces, banach-fixed-point

> Given the following function:
>
> $$g(z)=C*\begin{pmatrix}
>          x^2+y^2-2 \\
>          x^2-y^2-1 \\
>          \end{pmatrix}+z, \; \; \;z=(x,y)\in [0.93,1.52]\times [0.41,1]$$
>
> Prove that $g $ is a contraction for $C=\begin{pmatrix}
>          c & c \\
>          c & -c \\
>          \end{pmatrix}$

I looked at the Jacobian matrix of $g$ which is : $J=C*\begin{pmatrix}
        2x & 2y \\
        2x & -2y \\
        \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

However, I didn't find any norm such that $||J||\lt1$ which would prove that $g$ is in fact a contraction.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: What do you know about $c$?

Comment: This is clearly not a contraction for $c=0$.

Comment: how did you determine where $z$ belongs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your $*$ is matrix multiplication
$$J = \pmatrix{4cx+1 & 0\cr 0 & 4cy+1\cr}$$
so this will be a contraction with the Euclidean norm in any convex region where  $|4cx+1|<1$ and $|4cy+1|<1$.  For this to be true in your rectangle $(x,y) \in [0.93, 1.52] \times [0.41, 1]$ you need $-25/76 < c < 0$.